# Cabal update appears to be working but not doing anything

Tags: haskell, cabal, cairo

I just installed Haskell and have been trying to get it going, but when I tried to start it up, it does this:

```
C:\Users\isaac>cabal install
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 
'cabal update' to download it.
cabal: Error reading local package.
Couldn't find .cabal file in: .

C:\Users\isaac>cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
```

It has been like that for 10 hours now. I don't know if it's even possible to see how much progress, if any, it's made, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. The version is:

```
C:\Users\isaac>cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

All of this has been just to get Cairo working (on Windows).

Comment: Try `cabal update --verbose=3`?

Comment: As suggested by another commenter, you should run it with `--verbose=3` to see at which stage it hangs. On Windows, this is often (in my experience) a permission issue with some file that cabal is trying to write.